# How to copy entire HTML page body with values in input fields

Tags: html, jquery

I need to save the whole HTML page or a part of it into the database with all values entered by the user in input fields and the states of radio buttons etc... but when I try to do so the page is saved without the modifications made by the user.

**Is there any way to save them too?**

By "Save HTML page" i mean using jquery to save the innerHTML for a selector.

My goal is to save a particular section of my page on the server as HTML document after the user enters values in input fields. I managed to do that with jquery, but the problem is that the values which were entered by the user are not present in the saved document. so when i open the saved html, i want the values that were entered by the user to be shown in input fields. i dont want to collect them with JS and to fill them again, i just want to save the page as it is and view it later, i know this sounds like bull!@#% but this is what i have to do now.

Comment: "When I try to save HTML page with all values in input fields" - how are you trying to save the page? Please share your existing code and any errors from the console.

Comment: @JonP I am trying to do that with jquery, but i am ok with any alternative ways. there are no errors in the console, the problem is that the page is saved without the values in input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use jquery's attr().

example

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" id="input_1">
    <input type="text" id="input_2">
    <input type="text" id="input_3">
</div>
<button id="btn">save value</button>

<script>
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var $input = $('#inputs').find('input');
        var inputLen = $input.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < inputLen; i++) {
            $input.eq(i).attr('value', $input.eq(i).val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

On Chrome, print page, when the print dialog comes up save the destination to "save as a PDF" and the save the file.  Then just print the PDF file you saved.